# Build a URL using Requests module Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it possible to build a URL using the Requests library for Python?

Building a query string is supported but what about building the rest of the URL. Specifically I'd be interested in adding on to the base URL with URL encoded strings:

http :// some address.com/api/[term]/

term = 'This is a test'

http :// some address.com/api/This+is+a+test/

This is presumably possible using urllib but it seems like it would be better in Requests. Does this feature exist? If not is there a good reason that it shouldn't?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`requests` is basically a convenient wrapper around `urllib` (and 2,3 and other related libraries).

You can import `urljoin()`, `quote()` from [`requests.compat`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/d88cd02fd86c6e74ef8a2d1928db78b8976ce00f/requests/compat.py), but this is [essentially the same](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/d88cd02fd86c6e74ef8a2d1928db78b8976ce00f/requests/compat.py#L85-L115) as using them directly from `urllib` and `urlparse` modules:

```
>>> from requests.compat import urljoin, quote_plus
>>> url = "http://some-address.com/api/"
>>> term = 'This is a test'
>>> urljoin(url, quote_plus(term))
'http://some-address.com/api/This+is+a+test'
```

Comment: I like `requests.compat.urljoin` because it works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Addy - seems to work well for me. Can you be more specific in which scenarios it doesn't work?

Comment: can't find `urljoin` from `requests.compat`?